# как убрать повторяющиеся символы в строке? Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

```
*let someString = "Эта строка ничегоо не значит, но Суть в этомо чтобы научиться работать Со строками, и стать иOC Девелоперомоо"
var someText = ""
        for letters in someString {
            var counter = 0
            if letters == "о" {
                counter += 1
            } else {
                if counter > 1 {
                }
                someText.append(letters)
            }
            print(someText)*
```

Comment: Так надо убрать любые повторяющиеся символы или только гласные, или только `о`?  Вы знаете, что существует достаточно много слов, в которых буквы повторяются: `вообще-то кооператор-зоотехник более-менее аккуратно рассчитал классификацию воображаемых вооруженных лесоохранников на Сааремаа`

Comment: любой текст" - удалить каждую 2 букву "о" в слове

Comment: Так в слове `"девелопером"` есть две "законные" буквы `о`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант тестового кода, который оставляет в каждом слове только первую букву `о`:

```swift
let someString = "Эта строка ничегоо не значит, но Суть в этомо чтобы научиться работать Со строками, и стать иOC Девелоперомоо"
var someText = ""
var counter = 0

for letter in someString {
    var append = true    
    if (letter == " ") {
        counter = 0;
    } else if letter == "о" {
        counter += 1
        append = counter < 2
    }
    if (append) {
        someText.append(letter)
    }
}

print(someText)
```

Результат:

```
Эта строка ничего не значит, но Суть в этом чтобы научиться работать Со строками, и стать иOC Девелоперм
```

Правда, в таком случае от слова `Девелопером` остаётся `Девелоперм`

---

Если заменить условие, чтобы оставлять каждую нечётную букву `o` в слове (т.е. удалять каждую чётную) на следующее:

```swift
// ...
    else if letter == "о" {
        counter += 1
        append = (counter % 2 ) != 0
    }
// ...
```

то от слова `Девелоперомоо` останется `Девелопермо`:

```
Эта строка ничего не значит, но Суть в этом чтобы научиться работать Со строками, и стать иOC Девелопермо
```